# return multiple properties of financialdata

Tags: properties

Sorry, very silly newbie question.. regarding FinancialData, how to return multiple specified properties.

eg. if I want Open & Close properties , or perform an operation such as Open-Close

```
FinancialData["SP500","Open",{2015}]
FinancialData["SP500","Close",{2015}]
```

return daily Opening and Closing property values but as separate lists.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Tried using 'Union' but it seems a bit long winded to combine the lists.. is that the best? Need output with 3 columns, - date, open, close.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I use the MapIndexed & Join to add the Open-Close column too? Wish it was not so cryptic. I expected an SQL like language.

Comment: Easier to use `Table[{o[[i, 1]], o[[i, 2]], c[[i, 2]], o[[i, 2]] - c[[i, 2]]}, {i, Length[o]}]` to add the Open-Close column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining, for convenience,

```
o = FinancialData["SP500", "Open", {2015}]
c = FinancialData["SP500", "Close", {2015}]
```

the two can be combined into 3 columns, - date, open, close" with

```
MapIndexed[Join[#, c[[#2, 2]]] &, o]
(* {{{2015, 1, 2}, 2058.9, 2058.2}, {{2015, 1, 5}, 2054.44, 2020.58}, {{2015, 1, 6}, 2022.15, 2002.61}, ...} *)
```

Other methods include

```
Cases[MapThread[Join, {o, c}], {l1_, l2_, l3_, l4_} -> {l1, l2, l4}, Infinity]

Table[{o[[i, 1]], o[[i, 2]], c[[i, 2]]}, {i, Length[o]}]
```